# SQL Query to retrieve values that belong exclusively to a group

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have one table with the following values and columns:

```
ID1 | ID2
1   | 1
2   | 1
3   | 1
4   | 1
4   | 2
3   | 3
4   | 3
4   | 4
4   | 4
```

I'd like to retrieve the ID2 values that belong **exclusively** to records where ID1 = 4. So for the above example, I'd like to see the following response:

```
ID1 | ID2
4   | 2
4   | 4
```

Comment: "that belong to the same ID2" sounds a bit confusing to me. Could you clarify what do you mean?

Comment: When you say 'or just a count, in this case, 2.' what exactly do you mean?

Comment: 4 | 4 for the first results seems fine since what I understand is that you have the same ID on both columns but how 4 | 2 follows the same rule!  Of course, if I understood it right

Comment: Instead of paraphrasing the question, could you just post the actual question?

Comment: That's right @JorgeCampos. As indicated in my expected results, I'd like to see 4|4 and 4|2 being returned. That is, ID2 elements that ONLY have ID1 = 4

Comment: @mmmmmpie no sure what you mean by "paraphrasing" the question. I've provided an excerpt of what my table looks like and the expected result. Not sure what else I can provide.

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstand you but with this statement `That is, ID2 elements that ONLY have ID1 = 4` your expected result should be 4|1, 4|2,4|3,4|4 ? What am I missing??

Comment: @JorgeCampos He wants to find ID2 elements that **exclusively** belong to records where ID1 = 4. 1 and 3 belong to records where ID1 = 4 and other values as well, so they're not exclusive.

Comment: Now it makes sense. You should add this info on your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try working it out [contrapositively](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) like this.

Finding all elements where ID1 **is only** 4 is the same as finding all elements that **don't not** have ID1 = 4.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (ID1 NVARCHAR(10), ID2 NVARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO #temp(ID1,ID2) VALUES  (N'1',N'1')
INSERT INTO #temp(ID1,ID2) VALUES  (N'2',N'1')
INSERT INTO #temp(ID1,ID2) VALUES  (N'3',N'1')
INSERT INTO #temp(ID1,ID2) VALUES  (N'4',N'1')
INSERT INTO #temp(ID1,ID2) VALUES  (N'4',N'2')
INSERT INTO #temp(ID1,ID2) VALUES  (N'3',N'3')
INSERT INTO #temp(ID1,ID2) VALUES  (N'4',N'3')
INSERT INTO #temp(ID1,ID2) VALUES  (N'4',N'4')
INSERT INTO #temp(ID1,ID2) VALUES  (N'4',N'4')

SELECT * FROM #temp AS t

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM #temp AS t
WHERE id2 NOT IN (SELECT ID2 FROM #temp AS t WHERE ID1 <> 4)
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was missing. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

These queries will probably be useful to you for the more general cases (and by general I mean when ID1 is something other than 4):

```
select distinct t1.id1, t1.id2
from T as t1
where not exists (
    select 1
    from T as t2
    where t2.ID1 <> t1.ID1 and t2.ID2 = t1.ID2
)

select t1.id1, count(distinct t1.id2)
from T as t1
where not exists (
    select 1
    from T as t2
    where t2.ID1 <> t1.ID1 and t2.ID2 = t1.ID2
)
group by t1.id1
```

Comment: Perhaps DV will comment??

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
select 4,id2 from 
(select distinct ID1 , ID2 from t) t1
group by id2 
having count(*)=1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this:

```
SELECT t1.id1, t1.id2
  FROM mytable t1
 WHERE t1.id1 = 4
   AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM mytable t2
                     WHERE t2.id2 = t1.id2
                       AND t2.id1 != 4 );
```

or:

```
SELECT id1, id2 FROM (
    SELECT id1, id2
      FROM mytable
     GROUP BY id1, id2
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) WHERE id1 = 4;
```

or:

```
SELECT id1, id2 FROM (
    SELECT id1, id2, COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY id2 ) AS cnt
      FROM mytable
) WHERE id1 = 4
    AND cnt = 1;
```